# Where is the "Function Navigator" and "Virtual Book" gone?

Tags: version-10, version-9, documentation

Under V9 "Help" was a Item each for "Function Navigator" and "Virtual Book" to find and one could work with it.

[image]
[image]

Under V10 these Helpers are gone. Although under Documentation/English/System the NoteBook "DocumentationNavigator.nb" can still be found, if even with errors ...

[image]

I work with OSX10.9.4, this deficiency is also under Windows, Linux?

Is there a way to revive these functions?

I'm aware of Documentation Center.

Comment: The Function Navigator seems to be truly gone as separate entity, but some of its functionality is retained in a row of links running across the bottom of the home page of the Documentation Center.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Although I haven't examined it to see how complete it is, putting `Virtual Book` into the search bar of the Documentation Center quickly found this:

- http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/VirtualBookOverview.html

Which can be accessed locally with: `tutorial/VirtualBookOverview`

[image]

Answer (score 17):

*Update for V13*

Sometime by or before V13.0, the functionality changed, and it appears the old navigator is gone.  Now you can access the doc page (the same as in Mr.Wizard's answer) with this new syntax:

```
TreeBrowse`DocsNavigatorLookup[
 NotebookObject[Null], "paclet:tutorial/VirtualBookOverview"]
```

The first argument is unused. `DocsNavigatorLookup` now just executes the front end token `"OpenHelpLink"` on whatever doc page is passed as the second argument.

*Previous answer*

One may also call up the old navigator palette with

```
TreeBrowse`DocsNavigatorLookup[False]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: On Win 10/11 and MMA v13, @Mr.Wizard's method still works for accessing the Virtual Book.

Comment: @david Yes, I meant to imply that the V13 method I added does nothing more than call up tutorial/VirtualBookOverview, just like Mr.Wizard's, but by slightly a different mechanism. Principally I was explaining the new working of ``TreeBrowse`DocsNavigatorLookup``, since it seems the old navigator is now gone. Not sure why they left `DocsNavigatorLookup` in the system, esp. with a different syntax that breaks backwards compatibility.

Comment: Ah, I see that now.