# Mathematica 10 : Where is the Mathematica Book?

Tags: notebooks

The question is simple. In Mathematica 9, there used to be "The Mathematica Book" integrated with the software in the help system. I can't find it anymore in version 10. Do you know if it is still there ?

Best regards,
F.

Comment: Search for "Virtual Book": http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/VirtualBookOverview.html

Comment: Same thing is in the in-application tutorial/VirtualBookOverview. But how can one add a link to this on the *Mathematica 10* Help menu or, better, an icon link on the Documentation Center home page?

Comment: This will also bring up the Virtual Book/Function Navigator: ``TreeBrowse`DocsNavigatorLookup[False]``

Comment: Thanks. It is too bad it is hidden in such a way.

Comment: I see some close votes, but I don't think it is a good idea to close this question. For new users, the solutions offered in the comments are not readily found.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [Where (have) the “Function Navigator” and “Virtual Book” gone?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/54781/142).