# How can I change the default font size of the Virtual Book?

Tags: front-end, documentation

How can I change the default font size of the Virtual Book?

Answer (score 5):

In version 10 you can change the font size of the [Virtual Book](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/54787/280) by changing its `Magnification` but in previous versions of *Mathematica* the file

```
FindFile["DocumentationNavigator.nb"]
```

> C:\Program Files\Wolfram
>   Research\Mathematica\8.0\Documentation\English\System\DocumentationNavigator.nb

(which is the Virtual Book Notebook) has the option `Editable -> False` which prevents it from being changed in any way including changing the `Magnification` which is set to `1.`. For changing this you can (after making a backup copy of the original file) open this file in a text editor, then search for the strings "Editable->False" and "Saveable->False" and replace `False` with `True` in both cases, then save the file. After opening the file in *Mathematica* you will be notified that the file was changed outside of *Mathematica*. Just ignore it, set the `Magnification` you like and save the file. Now the Virtual Book will open with the `Magnification` you like (checked in version 8.0.4).

Answer (score 5):

An alternative to modifying `DocumentationNavigator.nb` using a text editor is to change the notebook's options programmatically.

Locate and open the notebook:

```
NotebookOpen[FindFile["DocumentationNavigator.nb"]]
```

Get the list of open notebooks using `Notebooks[]`:

```
nbks = Notebooks[]
```

`nbks[[2]]` is the notebook object we want to modify using `SetOptions`

using

```
SetOptions[nbks[[2]], {Editable -> True, Saveable -> True, Magnification -> 1.7}]
```

Before we hit `Shift-Enter`, this is how the notebook looks:

[image]

and after evaluating `SetOptions[...]` you get

[image]

Change the settings back:

```
SetOptions[nbks[[2]], {Editable -> True, Saveable -> True, Magnification -> 1.}]
```

[image]

Comment: How to find the available options such as `Editable -> True, Saveable -> True, Magnification`?

Comment: @qazwsx, `Options[nb]` gives the options for the notebook `nb`. Try, for example, `Options[EvaluationNotebook[]]` --  it is a long list.